# Is it possible to use ember-cli-addon-docs with an in-repo addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I have an ember.js in-repo addon and would like to add documentation using [ember-cli-addon-docs](https://github.com/ember-learn/ember-cli-addon-docs). Is this possible?

I installed the addon at application level and in my `ember-cli-build.js` I added:

```
'ember-cli-addon-docs': {
    documentingAddonAt: 'lib/my-addon',
},
```

but this does not work and I keep getting an error in my terminal:
`Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Was anyone successful with a simmilar setup

Answer (score 0):

This addon is quite peculiar.

It was initially designed to be used in other addons, and then hacked to be used in apps.

You are supposed to create an in-repo addon (you did this already), then reference it from your app's `package.json` like this:

```
  "ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "lib/my-addon"
    ]
  }
```